# Email not getting delivered when sent from yahoo

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

If I add a gmail email ID in the email field, it works but when I try to send using yahoo, I don't get the email :(

Any idea why this is happening and how do I fix it?

```
<?php
  $name    = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
  $email   = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
  $phone   = stripslashes($_POST['phone']);
  $city   = stripslashes($_POST['city']);
  $franchise = $_POST['franchise'];
  $experience = $_POST['experience'];
  $message = stripslashes($_POST['message']);
  $form_message = "Name: $name \nEmail: $email \nPhone: $phone \nCity: $city \nFranchise: $franchise \nExperience: $experience";

if ( $_POST['human'] ) {
  echo 'Tastes Like Spam!'; exit; }
else {
  header( "Location: http://www.example.com/success.php");
  mail("me@example.com", "Contact Us", $form_message, "From: $email" );
}
?>
```

Comment: check your spam

Comment: I recommend using http://swiftmailer.org/ . Because `mail` function can be broken depending to server.

Comment: I did that already. Tried sending with other non-yahoo mails and it works.

Comment: Check whether your SMTP server complies with all the rules of Yahoo. Think of SPF, DKIM, DMARC and reverse lookup, for instance. But most likely it doesn't like you using an email address that doesn't correspond with the domain you're sending from. Mail like that can disappear in a black hole. Here's a link: https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN3435.html

Answer (score 0):

You're using a user-submitted from address which means you are forging it, and will thus fail SPF checks. Your messages are also malformed and vulnerable to header injection attacks. Just don't use mail, use a library that protects you from this kind of thing like PJPMailer, that you tagged this question with.